# How change caching setting in django_cache_utils0.7 to cache the files in different directory other than C drive?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-cache

I am using django-cache-utils 0.7 where I am not able to change the cache directory to a drive location other than the default location. Please can anyone tell me how to define custom location and set a size limit on the folder ?

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'cache_utils.group_backend://localhost:11213/?timeout=600&max_entries=500'
```

When I try with path location instead of localhost it gives error.

Comment: What's the value of the `CACHES` setting in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: CACHE_BACKEND = 'cache_utils.group_backend://localhost:11213/?timeout=600&max_entries=500'   when I use path location instead of localhost it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache_utils.group_backend` is a cache backend that stores data in [memcached](http://memcached.org/). By itself it doesn't store it anywhere - on `C` drive or anywhere else. Memcached also doesn't keep its data on disk, but in memory (RAM).

As a consequence there is no right answer to your question.

If you want a cache backend that keeps its data on disk use [FileBasedCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching), but keep in mind that its much slower than memcached.

Comment: Thanks Ludwik Trammer,but I already knew about FileBasedCache wanted to avoid using FileBasedCache because of its disadvantages.

Comment: Please could you just let me know what major difference will it make when I use Django_cache_utils-2.0 instead of Django_cache_utils-0.7 ?